# How to create a report which include the formulas for every column without any grouping?

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I need to create a report which have to calculate the values based on two fields and need to populate in 3rd field.

Example:

> > Column1 is having the **Quantity**
> >
> > Column2 is having the **Price**
> >
> > And in Column3, I want the Multiplication of **Quantity** and **Price** for every row.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only summary formulas are available in reports. But you can create a formula field on the object to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But my problem on creating formula field on object is that, I am getting those required fields from different objects where i cannot create those many formula fields and lookups to create the multiplication in reports

Answer (score 1):

As Oleksiy says, you can't create formula fields in tabular reports.

You should be able to use cross-object formula fields on your target object

For example, if object `Foo__c` has a lookup to `Bar__c`, then you can create a formula field on `Foo__c`, let's call it `TotalPrice__c` =

```
quantity__c * Bar__r.price__c
```

and use `TotalPrice__c` in the report.

If this doesn't work for you, another option is to use an AppExchange Product like Conga Composer where the results from one or more SFDC reports/queries can be combined together and manipulated with excel formulas/pivots before presenting to the user. I've used this in the past where one SFDC report simply isn't sufficiently expressive to bring all the different data sources into one nice single sheet presentation